# Find second probable search group with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a regex (https://regex101.com/r/eYzXfZ/2/) with python.
 My current re:

```
^[\d\W]{8}((?=.*Start execution of )|(?=.*Finish execution of))
```

Now it is looking for time at the beginning of the line, if the line contains the necessary substring, but I can’t think of any way how to make the second group in the search, where the status will also be found (indicated in square brackets), if it is in the corresponding line.
So, for example, after using regular expression on the following lines:

```
01:01:01 - Start executing steps 1-3
01:01:03 - Start execution of steps group
01:01:04 - Start execution of step [1]
01:02:12 - Finish execution of step [1] with status [ok]
01:02:13 - Start execution of step [2]
01:02:48 - Finish execution of step [2] with status [ok]
01:02:48 - Start execution of step [3]
01:13:21 - Finish execution of step [3] with status [ok]
01:13:21 - Finish execution of steps group with status [success]
01:13:22 - Finish executing steps 1-3
```

I expect to return:

```
['01:01:03', 
 '01:01:04', 
('01:02:12', 'ok'), 
 '01:02:13', 
('01:02:48', 'ok'), 
 '01:02:48', 
('01:13:21', 'ok'), 
('01:13:21', 'success')]
```

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/xF3Uyj/1 might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Regex

```
(^[\d:]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[([a-zA-Z]+))?)
```

[Link to Regex](https://regex101.com/r/dlnKoM/3)

## Output

Based on the output that you wanted, the above regex will get you exactly what you want. As you can see, it has all the needed **timings** along with the optional **status**; with nothing extra!

```
01:01:03
01:01:04
01:02:12, ok
01:02:13
01:02:48, ok
01:02:48
01:13:21, ok
01:13:21, success
02:01:02
02:01:02
02:03:10, ok
02:03:12
02:03:16, fail
02:03:16, failed
```

## Differences

You will see that it differs from yours in several key areas

1. You want the timings, so you have to group them in parenthesis `(^[\d:]{8})`.
2. You want just the digits and colons in the timings, so the regex makes that clear. `[\d:]` vs `[\d\W]`

   Note: with (2) above, this also works `(^[\d:]+)`
3. It removes the look ahead group. You don't need to group this look ahead as you don't want that text returned in your Python code. So removed the extra parenthesis!
4. Combines the 2 lookaheads into one. `(?:Start|Finish) execution of`
5. Added your missing requirement of the status `(?:.*\[([a-zA-Z]+))?` within the look ahead. This should be captured, so you need the parenthesis within the square brackets!

## Other Viable Regex

```
# Implicit status label, explicit letters for status
(^[\d:]+)(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[([a-zA-Z]+))?)
(^[\d:]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[([a-zA-Z]+))?)
(^[\d\W]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[([a-zA-Z]+))?)

# Explicit status label, explicit letters for status
(^[\d:]+)(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*status \[([a-zA-Z]+))?)
(^[\d:]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*status \[([a-zA-Z]+))?)
(^[\d\W]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*status \[([a-zA-Z]+))?)

# Explicit status label, implicit letters for status
(^[\d:]+)(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*status \[(.*?)\])?)
(^[\d:]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*status \[(.*?)\])?)
(^[\d\W]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*status \[(.*?)\])?)

# NOTE: FAILS - Implicit status label and implicit letter for status 
# (^[\d:]+)(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[(.*?)\])?)
# (^[\d:]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[(.*?)\])?)
# (^[\d\W]{8})(?=.*(?:Start|Finish) execution of (?:.*\[(.*?)\])?)


# Answers from other posters

^([\d\W]{8})(?=(?=.*Start execution of )|(?=.*Finish execution of))(?=.*?status \[(.*?)\])?


# Customize

# If you prefer the split lookahead, then you can customize any of the above with the middle section
# For example...
(^[\d:]+)(?=(?=.*Start execution of )|(?=.*Finish execution of)(?:.*\[([a-zA-Z]+))?)
```

Comment: `(^.{8}+)` and `(^[\S]+)` are also good captures for the timings that are both shorter than above

Answer (score 1):

You can append the following to your regex:

```
.*?status \[(.*?)\]
```

therefore it becomes:

```
^([\d\W]{8})(?=(?=.*Start execution of )|(?=.*Finish execution of))(?=.*?status \[(.*?)\])?
```

See it online: https://regex101.com/r/t2y6sD/2